# Basic Node.js setup on Windows

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to get node.js to run a sample script I've created. I'm using Windows. `mysamplescript.js` is in the same folder as the node.js executable. When I type in

```
node mysamplescript.js
```

I get `...` returned on the next line.  The docs for node aren't exactly stellar. Am I missing something?

Comment: Have you runned the installer for node.js that you can download from nodejs.org?

Comment: Posting the code in `mysamplescript.js` would be useful as it appears node.exe **is** in your path.

Comment: Are you sure you are NOT inside the node.hs REPL? The ... happens when you are inside the Node.js REPL and Node thinks your command will continue in the next line. If you run "node myscript.js" from the DOS prompt you shouldn't be in the REPL, node should just execute your script, though.